# Lotus notes 8.5 team mailbox auto out of office

Tags: lotus-notes

Within our organisation we use lotus notes team mailbox and there is an auto out of hours message being returned to all who contact our address.

Turns out or DB doesnt know how to turn this off - do you?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using [Domino Team Mailbox from OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=DominoTeamMailbox).

From the [documentation](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/documentation.xsp?documentId=A0E3537E7260564B86257641006DC557&action=openDocument):
To access preferences, open the team mailbox and click on the "Team Mailbox" logo in the upper-left. Then open the "Mailbox Preferences". You can then go to the Auto Reply tab and disable the Auto Reply option.

Answer (score 0):

If it's using a standard mailfile design and not a customized one, the out of office is usually in more-->out of office.